# How to set WP Cron job timestamp according to timezone?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, cron

I'm using server cron job at midnight to schedule a WP event to send updates to the customers regarding their expired products. Whatever I have written the time is converted to my UTC+5 timezone.

PHP Code:

```
function register_daily_expired_products_event() {
    if (!wp_next_scheduled('send_emails')) {

        // Schedule daily expired products event
        wp_schedule_event(strtotime('today midnight'), 'daily', 'ptmp_notify_customers');
    }
}

add_action('init', 'register_daily_expired_products_event');

function ptmp_send_product_expiry_emails() {
    // Custom code
}

// Notify customers with their expired products
add_action('ptmp_notify_customers', 'ptmp_send_product_expiry_emails');
```

Tested cron job event with WP Crontrol plugin that is showing +5hours according to my timezone(UTC+5). e.g.

**Time should be:** 2017-07-08 00:00:00

**But in actual:** 2017-07-08 05:00:00 (Added plus 5 hours)

And server cron job is running at exact 12:00 AM but at the backend, the event has more 5 hours and not ready to be executed. So, no email sent even the customers have expired products at that day. Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you want to adapt your serverside cronjob execution time to your users timezone.

There are two ways, you could do.

### a) all users are in the same timezone

If your customers are all in the same timezone, you've to adapt your cronjob execution time to that specific timezone.

### b) users have different timezones

If your customers are not in the same timezone, you have to run your cronjob every hour (or every 30 mins, 15mins...) and check the time against your users timezone.

**so your cronjob (i.e. every hour) should do something like this:**

1. get all expired products
2. get the timezone of the user the products belong to
3. check if the current time is around 00:00 of the user's timezone
4. if so, send notification email

Have a look at the official PHP-documentation on how to set the timezone:
http://php.net/manual/de/datetime.settimezone.php

Comment: Thank you for providing the detailed description. It also helped me. My question is how to get the timestamp according to my timezone. As this time is plus 5 hours with UTC. Time should be: 2017-07-08 00:00:00

But in actual: 2017-07-08 05:00:00 (Added plus 5 hours) UTC+5